# What does >+ and >- mean in C#

Tags: c#, .net, operators

I had accidentally tried this, which compiles! So I was wondering what could this possibly mean.. google didnt help..

```
if (3 >+ 4)
   dothis() //this is never hit btw..

if (3 >- 4)
   dothis() //this is hit.
```

Both the code compile btw..

Comment: yea rightly commented by leppie

Comment: Oh very stupid of me. thanks guys. Can I close the question?

Comment: Btw. did you know the goes to operator `i --> 0` and the comes from operator `0 <-- i`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator

Comment: @CodeInChaos no what does that mean?

Comment: No reason to downvote this into oblivion. The question is clear and has code that exhibits the problem. While the answer may be obvious, sometimes one has a bit of a brainfart. The `-->` question is a bit cooler, but essentially the same thing, and it got hundreds of upvotes.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: agreed; the question is perfectly legit. Hopefully the next guy who runs into this can simply Google for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It parses as

```
3 > +4
```

and

```
3 > -4
```

So into the [unary `+`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691365%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [unary `-`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691366%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) operators.

If you want an interesting way to explore this, write

```
Expression<Func<int, int, bool>> func = (x, y) => x >+ y;
```

and then explore the resulting expression tree `func` in the debugger. You'll see the unary operator in the tree.

Answer (score 2):

Is 3 greater than 4?

Is 3 greather than -4?

If you're ever in doubt about what something is doing, write a little test app:

```
  int i = +3;
  int j = -4;

  Console.WriteLine(i);
  Console.WriteLine(j);

  Console.WriteLine((3 > +4));
  Console.WriteLine((3 > -4));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting a semicolon after dothis() like

```
dothis();
```

Then watch what happens to the + and - operator. They will be shifted away from greater or less than sigh and move nearer to 4.

```
if (3 > +4)
   dothis() //this is never hit btw.. 
            //will never hit in the entire universe

if (3 > -4)
   dothis() //this is hit
            //will always be a hit
```

First becomes if 3 > +4 (Positive 4) which will always result in false.

Second becomes if 3 > -4 (Negative 4) which will always result in true.